# Pentaho to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pentaho

I'm trying to put some data from a Pentaho job into Elasticsearch. I've not been able to get the Elastic Search Bulk Insert step to work, so have decided to take the approach of using a JSON step followed by the REST client step.

I can get it to send my data into Elasticsearch fine, however when the data goes into Elasticsearch it is all under the structure of block starting with the field:

```
"data:[".
```

It actually looks like this:

```
"_source":{"data":[{"Field1":"Value1","Field2":"Value2}]
```

If I want to query anything I have to search Elasticsearch for `"data.THINGIWANTTOFIND"` and not just `"THINGIWANTTOFIND"`. Is there a way to get around that?

It appears I need to somehow remove the `{"data":[` part of the `"_source"`field.

The word "data" relates to the "JSON bloc name" in the JSON step in Pentaho, but I've tried changing it and removing it and it still has the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to clean it up (i.e. remove/change/rename/whatever the `data` field) before sending the JSON to ES. Can you show a full sample document that you get from Pentaho?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a replace in string step to clear up the JSON and it's now working as expected.

Comment: What if you share your solution ? :) The Elasticsearch Bulk Step is not working fine ...